# SQL injection with function call

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-injection

Following query gets executed in my program, where 'a' is the parameter value which I am taking as input & passing it in query.

```
select * from emp where name LIKE LOWER('%a%')
```

Can anybody tell me whether I can do SQL injection attack on above query or is it safe?

I have seen SQL injection with where clause & like operator but can we do it with function call as well. What can I pass as the instead of 'a' for SQL injection.

I am using PL/SQL editor & Oracle DB.

Comment: How are you "passing it in query"? Replacing "a" with your parameter and passing the resulting string to Oracle? Something else?

Answer (score 4):

Risk of SQL-injection appears when your application interacts with environment (other program or user) and assembles SQL query from parts using string concatenation. For example, you can write PL/SQL procedure:

```
create or replace procedure myproc(a varchar2) is
  sql_str varchar2(4000);
  sql_result number;
begin
  execute immediate 'select count(*) from mytable where mycolumn = ' || a into sql_result;
end;
```

This procedure is vulnerable. You can pass there a string `''abc''' or 1 = 1` or anything like this and it distorts result (or made something worse).
Or you can write it like this:

```
create or replace procedure myproc(a varchar2) is
  sql_str varchar2(4000);
  sql_result number;
begin
  execute immediate 'select count(*) from mytable where mycolumn = :A' using a into sql_result;
end;
```

And this procedure is not vulnerable.
Also you can write

```
create or replace procedure myproc(a varchar2) is
  sql_str varchar2(4000);
  sql_result number;
begin
  select count(*) 
    into sql_result
    from mytable 
   where mycolumn = a;
end;
```

Here is no problems at all, it is the most secure way (it is "static SQL"), but sometimes we need dynamic SQL (like in first two examples).
Why first way is bad and second is good? It is because SQL engine compiles queries almost like other compilers compile their code, like C++ for example. SQL engine compiles query as a "program" and defines possible "variables" in this "program". "Variable" in second procedure is the parameter `:A`. If query contains "variables", engine asks their values (`USING` clause) and passes them into compiled query. In first case engine gets concatenated string:

```
select count(*) from mytable where mycolumn = 'abc' or 1 = 1
```

considers it like a whole "program" and executes it "as is". In second case engine gets string

```
select count(*) from mytable where mycolumn = :A
```

compiles it, defines 1 "variable" `A` and asks it value, and then passes it to a "program", and that "program" just searches value `'abc' or 1 = 1` in column `mycolumn`. This works not only with dynamic SQL in PL/SQL code. It works the same way in any language, and all popular frameworks (for java, c#, delphi, etc.) and all popular DBMS provide instruments for safe work as in second example.
Of course, it was simplified example, sometimes consequences could be much more worse.

Answer (score 1):

a can be

```
   1') or 1 = 1 or LIKE LOWER('1
```

You should make sure the values passed as a are clean maybe by stripping the slashes in a.

Comment: I am getting syntax error for above statement. ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated

Comment: Sorry after the last 1 = 1 there should be or LIKE LOWER('1 before " making a = "1') or 1 = 1 or LIKE LOWER('1";

Comment: Still could not get it, can you please give me the complete SQL statement such that there is some SQL getting passed inside Lower function

Comment: I have edited my answer the complete statement is there

Comment: Here is the complete query select * from emp where name LIKE  LOWER('a = "1') or 1 = 1 or LIKE LOWER('1";')      I am getting error for this ORA-00936: missing expression

Comment: I got it thanks a lot. Here it is select * from emp where name LIKE  LOWER('a = "1') or 1 = 1 OR NAME LIKE ('TEST')

Comment: You should remove the a = ", the last double quotes " and semicolon ; it should be  select * from emp where name LIKE  LOWER('1') or 1 = 1 or LIKE LOWER('1')

Comment: Hey but I want to pass the Delete/Update statement in place of 'a' . How can I do that in the above query?

Comment: Try using this as a, I'm not sure if it works 1'); DROP TABLE emp; select * from emp where name LIKE LOWER('1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75788/discussion-between-atul-sureka-and-chuksy).

Answer (score 1):

You can exploit SQL Injection almost anywhere.
Checkout my white paper, Google "SQL Injection Anywhere" that demonstrates injections in weird places - including function calls.